# Where does a mov instruction exactly execute in a modern cpu (considering an 80x86 assembly language)?

Tags: cpu

I'm a bit confused where a simple mov instruction executes as from the components I know a modern cpu usually has I see no place where it could be executed, I know that in a simplified Von Neumann architecture it could be considered that an ALU is in charge of executing the mov instructions (I wouldn't exactly call it ALU in this case, but whatever...).

I know about those 4 components of a CPU that are in charge of executing instructions:

ALU: For executing arithmetical, logical and bit shift operations.

FPU: For arithmetical and bit shift operations on floating point numbers.

AGU: For calculating adresses to access main memory.

MMU: To transform virtual memory adresses to physical adresses.

But problem is that I just don't see any of those things from that description to perform simple things like the following, which are pretty common:

mov ax, 5

mov al, [bx]

mov [bx],110

Then, where is a mov instruction executed once it has been decoded?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This appears to be a homework question.  A .MOV instruction is a memory operation.  You are loading a value from a particular address into another address.

Comment: Well, I  think it's not necessarily a memory operation, you can also do a MOV register, inmediate or MOV register, register. Anyway that doesn't answer my question, as I'm asking about the CPU component that performs the execution, I mean the part that does something like "ok, I've got a memory direction and an operand, let's put the direction into the memory bus, the operand into the data bus and then I give a signal so that memory position is loaded with that operand".

Comment: From what I remember from college courses (long ago), it's the CPU itself.